# Set email length limit

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I have an form with an email field. I want to set the input limit which is maximum 45 characters for the field or else a error message will show.

```
<v-text-field
   v-model="Email"
   :rules="[rules.required, rules.email]"
   label="Email"
></v-text-field>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
   
      email: (value) => {
          if(value.length > 0) {
            const pattern =
              /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return pattern.test(value) || "Please enter a valid email.";
          } else if (value.length > 45) {
            return pattern.test(value) || "Maximum email length is 45 characters.";
          }
        },
    })
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new rule called `emailLength` that checks if the value of email is greater than 45 characters. If it is, it returns an error message.

```
<v-text-field
   v-model="Email"
   :rules="[rules.required, rules.email, rules.emailLength]"
   label="Email"
></v-text-field>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
   
      email: (value) => {
          if(value.length > 0) {
            const pattern =
              /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return pattern.test(value) || "Please enter a valid email.";
          }
        },
    emailLength: (value) => {
          if (value.length > 45) {
            return "Maximum email length is 45 characters.";
          }
    }
    })
  }
</script>
```

This new rule should be added to the `rules` array of the v-text-field component.

Answer (score 0):

Initially when the value is null or empty, then `value.length > 0` will always throw an error for calling the length property on a null value. So use `if (value)` instead.

Now, if the email input has some value then control will always go inside the first `if` statement, and the second `if` statement will never get executed, so the length validation will never be applied.

**Tip-**
You don't need to handle the case `if (value)` or  `if (value.length > 0)` because `rules.required` is already there for this validation.

Try replacing your rule with the following-

```
email: (value) => {
  const pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  if (!pattern.test(value)) {
    return "Please enter a valid email.";
  }
  if (value.length > 45) {
    return "Maximum email length is 45 characters.";
  }
  return true;
},
```

A working example in JS with the above validation rule. (I used a length limit of 10 for the demo.)

```js
function validate(value) {
  const pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  if (!pattern.test(value)) {
    console.log("Please enter a valid email.");
    return;
  }
  if (value.length > 10) {
    console.log("Maximum email length is 10 characters.");
    return;
  }
  console.log("GOOD JOB");
}
```

```html
<input name="email" oninput="validate(this.value)"/>
```